# PHP variable condition based jQuery tab hide

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to hide jQuery tab according to php variable value. Tried by putting php validation at below but page fails to render.

```
<?php
$myJob = "Install";
?>

$(document).ready(function () {

    var jobStatus = $(".jobs-status").dataTable({
        aLengthMenu: [ [10, 25, 50, 100, 150, "-1"], [10, 25, 50, 100, 150, "All"] ],
        iDisplayLength: 10,
        searching: true,
        "aaSorting": [],
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        columnDefs: [ { orderable: true } ],

        "bProcessing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "cache": false,
        "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo $jobs_status; ?>",

        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "ip" },
            { "data": "machine" },
        ],
    });


    $('#tabs').tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            var $activeTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');

            if ($activeTab == 0) {
                $('#seachdiv').show();

            } else if ($activeTab == 1) {
                $('#seachdiv').hide();
                jobStatus.fnClearTable( 0 );
                jobStatus.fnSort( [ 0, "desc" ] );
                jobStatus.fnDraw();

            }

        }
    });
});
```

What code I should write here to hide tab #1 if PHP variable `$myJob == "Upgrade"`?

Comment: Put the variable in a hidden field and get the value using jQuery.

Comment: Actually dynamic value coming to php variable and i want to hide based on that on client side code. Can you code your way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php if ($myJob === "Upgrade") { ?>
  $('[href="#tabs1"]').closest('li').hide();
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Wissem, it just requires additional hide as well. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Output your PHP variable as a JavaScript variable like so:

```
<?php
echo "<script>var myJob = ".json_encode($myJob).";</script>";
?>
```

Now the `myJob` variable will be available to your JavaScript code.

If you have multiple variables that need this treatment, you might consider doing them all together in one call -- `json_encode()` can accept arrays or objects and will output the equivalent JS object structure, so you could write one line to output your entire config array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
$($("#tabs").find("li")[1]).hide();
$($("#tabs").find('#tab1')).hide();
```